# Вставить переменную PHP

Tags: php

Как вставить переменную между тегами `p`

```
$message = '
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
<body>
 <p>Например тут</p>
</body>
</html>';
```

Comment: `Например тут` на `'.$xyz.'`

Comment: А еще можно заменить одинарные кавычки на двойные и тупо вставить переменную в нужное место строки

Comment: Или на `{$var}`

Comment: Не делайте так. Написал в ответе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> PHP исполняет код, находящийся внутри ограничителей, таких как `<?php ?>`.
>   Всё, что находится вне ограничителей, выводится без изменений. В
>   основном это используется для вставки PHP-кода в HTML-документ...

**Правильное применение PHP в контексте с HTML-разметкой**

```php
<html>
 <head>
  <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
 </head>
<body>
 <p><?php echo $myVar; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Правильно, и удобнее будет для вас в дальнейшем, если будете организовывать структуру своего проекта следующим образом: скрипт «вставлять» в HTML-разметку, а не PHP выводить разметку (если она конечно из чего-то не генерируется).

Это основы синтаксиса.

Если в дальнейшем захотите использовать какой-нибудь шаблонизатор — также будет проще для вас.

**Дополнительная информация**

- [**Что такое PHP?**](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro-whatis.php)
- [Изолирование от HTML](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

Comment: На вывод первой переменной посмотрите.

Comment: @Visman спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 5):

Еще есть такой вариант, более лаконичный, на мой взгляд

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title><?=$title?></title>
 </head>
<body>
 <p><?=$myVar?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: И как человеку вывести информацию пользователю используя ваш ответ?

Comment: Попробуйте сами. Объявите в сценарии php, который подключен, например, перед html кодом, в котором находятся указанные переменные, а ниже эту часть кода.
Но опять же, это запись конкретно под тот пример, который указали Вы, где используется конструкция вывода вида: 
<тэг><?php echo $a; ?> </тэг>. 
Вариант который указал я - это короткая запись <?php echo "что-то" ?>